# How to add geo autocomplete?

Tags: python

I have a python code that returns me full geo address of some address:

```
import geocoder 
g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA')
print(g.address)

'Mountain View, CA, USA'
```

Is there any way to return 10 most relevant address, not just one?

Comment: What would the 10 most relevant addresses be from that very specific search query?

Comment: @Torxed Maybe it's a bad example, but in general if a street present in couple cities, I wanna to see these cities.

Comment: I understand what you need now, however I'm not entirely sure this library supports it. There's mentionings of `nearby` or `ambigious` search queries - but no where are they documented. However, you appear to be able to do: `geocoder.google('restaurants near Mountain View, CA', method='places')` and that gives you places near by. As far as I can tell, there's no way to get like a top-10 search hits based on a ambigious street address - even tho they mention this in the code: https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder/blob/289633117687f442e4e0adc62a25b16786828a88/geocoder/google.py#L21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have found reading the documents and example code of `geocoder` package, `geocoder.google()` method returns only one result.

If you search for nearby hospitals using `geocoder` with the following code:

```
import geocoder
res = geocoder.google("nearby hospitals")
print(res.address)
```

will output only one result:

```
1125 E Main St, Columbus, OH 43205, USA
```

I have tested this in https://c9.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use google api service for this

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mountain%20View

the api will return a json string, u can get full address from that json data